# Create fstab entry with 777 permissions and no auto mount

Tags: permissions, mount, samba

I don't quite understand how fstab works but I'm having permission issues with a Windows Samba share that I am trying to mount.

normally I mount it using the following

```
mount -t cifs -o username=myname,password=12345 //10.10.0.78/smb /share/smb
```

I prefer to use the manual mount instead of auto mounting but I was wondering if it is possible to create an fstab entry to allow 777 permissions on this mounted directory

Answer (score 1):

```
//10.10.0.78/smb /share/smb cifs username=YOURUSERNAME,password=YOURPASSWORD,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```

Comment: A bit of explanation is in order.

Comment: Will this not automatically mount it on boot?

Comment: I forgot. You want to  mount it manual.  So noauto is required to. And look the permissions of the Mountpoint too.